# Nothing happen Submit Post phpmailer + AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, email, phpmailer

I´ve a simple 3 pages html. Index, contact and services. I call the templates views html with ng-view. All is fine. I see them with buttons navbar.

In contact.html, I want use the phpmailer and tutorial from "http://www.chaosm.net/blog/2014/05/21/angularjs-contact-form-with-bootstrap-and-phpmailer/".

In my controller, I paste the code JS in new controller, and in my html file the same form fron tutorial. After differents tests, I reach the controller  working but when I pulse the input submit:nothing happen and doesn´t send anything.

I change the path relative to my exampledomain.net/js/contact-form.php in the code controller. Change so in contact-form the path for the call to PHPMailerAutoload.php.

In the contactform.html, I put in first div the call to controller ) and same form example.

In contact-form.php all is the same like the tutorial, only I change the path like I write before).

Is posible the post form doesn´t work because I use ng-view? Someone have 1 idea why contact-form.php seem not running?

### I´m very beginner in Angular JS. thanks

The code of the unique controller I have (for routing and form phpmailer):

```
//Creo modulo y su nbre + establecer function routage
var AppSol = angular.module('AppSol', ['ngRoute']);

//Configure routage

    AppSol.config(function($routeProvider){

        $routeProvider

        //Indico links pages nav

        .when ('/',{
            templateUrl:'templates/home.html',
            controller:''

        })

        .otherwise ({
                    redirectTo:"/"
        })

        .when ('/Inicio',{
            templateUrl:'templates/home.html',
            controller:'MainCtrl'

        })  

        .when ('/Contacto',{
            templateUrl:'templates/contacto.html',
            controller:'ContactController'

        })  

        .when ('/Servicios',{
            templateUrl:'templates/servicios.html',
            controller:'ServCtrl'

        }); 

    });

        //Creo controller and lo injecto
        AppSol.controller ('MainCtrl', function($scope){

        //Probar que funciona con mensaje
        $scope.titulo="MY TITLE";


        });


        //Creo controller and lo injecto
        AppSol.controller ('ServCtrl', function($scope){

        //Probar que funciona con mensaje
        $scope.message='';
        $scope.titulo='SECOND TITLE'       

        });





        //Creo controller and lo injecto

        AppSol.controller ('ContactController', function ($scope, $http) {
        $scope.titulo='TEST1 CALL CONTACT CONTROLLER'   
        //$scope.result = 'Hidden'
        $scope.resultMessage='Test2 with Result control - I see this mensaje.';
        $scope.formData; //formData is an object holding the name, email, subject, and message
        $scope.submitButtonDisabled = false;
        $scope.submitted = false; //used so that form errors are shown only after the form has been submitted
        $scope.submit = function(contactform) {
            $scope.submitted = true;
            $scope.submitButtonDisabled = true;
            if (contactform.$valid) {
                $http({
                    method  : 'POST',
                    url     : 'http://exampledomain.net/test/js/contact-form.php',
                    data    : $.param($scope.formData),  //param method from jQuery
                    headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }  //set the headers so angular passing info as form data (not request payload)
                }).success(function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                    if (data.success) { //success comes from the return json object
                        $scope.submitButtonDisabled = true;
                        $scope.resultMessage = data.message;
                        $scope.result='bg-success';
                    } else {
                        $scope.submitButtonDisabled = false;
                        $scope.resultMessage = data.message;
                        $scope.result='bg-danger';
                    }
                });
            } else {
                $scope.submitButtonDisabled = false;
                $scope.resultMessage = 'Failed :( Please fill out all the fields.';
                $scope.result='bg-danger';
            }
        }
    });








            Of course:


            <div class="jumbotron" ng-app="AppSol">
            <div class="container">
            <div id="corte"></div>



            <div class="vertical-middle">
            <div class="container">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
            <h2 class="panel-title">Contact Form</h2>              <strong>{{titulo}} for test controller form</strong>
            </div>
            <div ng-controller="ContactController" class="panel-body">
            <form ng-submit="submit(contactform)" name="contactform" method="post" action="" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
            <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': contactform.inputName.$invalid && submitted }">
            <label for="inputName" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Name</label>
            <div class="col-lg-10">
            <input ng-model="formData.inputName" type="text" class="form-control" id="inputName" name="inputName" placeholder="Your Name" required>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': contactform.inputEmail.$invalid && submitted }">
            <label for="inputEmail" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Email</label>
            <div class="col-lg-10">
            <input ng-model="formData.inputEmail" type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" name="inputEmail" placeholder="Your Email" required>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': contactform.inputSubject.$invalid && submitted }">
            <label for="inputSubject" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Subject</label>
            <div class="col-lg-10">
            <input ng-model="formData.inputSubject" type="text" class="form-control" id="inputSubject" name="inputSubject" placeholder="Subject Message" required>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': contactform.inputMessage.$invalid && submitted }">
            <label for="inputMessage" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Message</label>
            <div class="col-lg-10">
            <textarea ng-model="formData.inputMessage" class="form-control" rows="4" id="inputMessage" name="inputMessage" placeholder="Your message..." required></textarea>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-10">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" ng-disabled="submitButtonDisabled">
                Send Message
            </button>
            </div>
            </div>
            </form>
            <p ng-class="result" style="padding: 15px; margin: 0;">{{ resultMessage }}</p>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Check your web server access logs and add some logging to your PHP; that way you will see what is being requested.

Comment: With mine, nothing is in log. If i try the original files, it´s working and I see in log the form I send. Is for that I believe is a problem with call request form or my controller is not good or something happen because I use ng-view for call in folder template contact.html.

Comment: So start with the working code and swap in sections of your new code until it breaks, then you will know where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

View is ok, so you can add error to your $http promise, and see what is the server response.

Comment: Can you help me more? give your mail adress please?

Comment: Hi all, Someone can tell me more. I put a alert when check form... I see the alert but same problem, page refresh without post anything. I believe it´s because I´ve use ng-view for call contact.html and have something wrong with angular use or in my controller. Thanks,

Comment: Sorry for late response, did  you solve the problem or need help ?